# Many attributes don't work in themes in android

Tags: android, material3

Many attributes don't work. How do I find out which attribute should be used in each specific case?

Here I took as an example the replacement of the color of the title text in the toolbar:

```
<style name="CustomToolbar" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">#03A9F4</item>
<!--        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item> - not worked-->
<!--        <item name="color">@color/white</item> - not worked-->
<!--        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> - not worked-->
<!--        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/white</item> - not worked-->
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item> - worked!
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.Workshop2" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/CustomToolbar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#03A9F4</item>
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>
```